# Can/should client app provide its own login page?

Tags: identityserver3

I am very new to IdentityServer and Open ID Connect and most of what I know comes through the three walk throughs in the Overview section of the IdentityServer3 documentation. All of those samples demonstrate how to use the Authorize attribute to secure a controller action, which results in a redirect to the IdentityServer-hosted login page. What is the typical or recommended way to provide a Login link in the client application? Could my client application have it's own login page and then call IdentityServer to validate the login and provide a token? If so, is there a sample that shows this? If not, is there a way to have the login link in my application bring up the IdentityServer login page? Is it as simple as securing the Login action with an Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is right that client has its own login page. Imagine you use Facebook as identity provider, and would you expect facebook users to enter their Facebook crediential on your login page?

One method is what you described using server side challenge redirect, or configure your app as a Javascript implicit client - [see example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient-Simple) , which it builds up authroize challenge URL. Either way user sees login page from identity server.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've seen some sample sites where a locally hosted login page provides local login and separate buttons for external logins. I'm not arguing for that approach. The local login page is just what I'm used to. I'm working through the IdentityServer3 JavaScript walk through, which is also a JavaScript implicit client, so I see now how to implement my local login button without hosting the login UI in my app.